# Text based games: moving room-to-room

Tags: python

```
# data setup
rooms = {'Great Hall': {'name': 'Great Hall', 'south': 'Bedroom',
        'text': 'You are in the Great Hall.'},
        
    'Bedroom': {'name': 'the bedroom', 'east': 'Cellar', 'north': 'Great Hall',
        'text': 'You are in the Bedroom.'},  
    'Cellar': {'name': 'the Cellar', 'west': 'Bedroom',
        'text': 'You are in the Cellar.'}
    }
directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
current_room = rooms['Great Hall']
 
# game loop
while True:
    # display current location
 
    print('You are in {}.'.format(current_room['name']))
   
    # get user input
    command = input('\nWhat do you do?')
    # movement
    if command in directions:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
        elif rooms[3] == 'Cellar':
            print('Congratulations! You have reached the cellar and defeated the Dragon!')
            break
        else:
            # bad movement
            print('You cannot go that way.')
    # quit game
    elif command == 'quit':
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break
    # bad command
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
```

Above is the code I have so far to move from room-to-room in a text based game. I am having trouble coding reaching the cellar room and having the player "win" the game. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @JeffUK '`command` is never going to be in both `directions` and `current_room`' - yes it is

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking the name of `current_room` at the start of each 'game loop' for the win condition (if it is 'the Cellar'). Try the following as your `while` loop:

```
while True:
    if current_room['name'] == 'the Cellar':
        print('Congratulations! You have reached the cellar and defeated the Dragon!')
        break
    # display current location
    print('You are in {}.'.format(current_room['name']))
   
    # get user input
    command = input('\nWhat do you do?')
    # movement
    if command in directions:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
        else:
            # bad movement
            print('You cannot go that way.')
    # quit game
    elif command == 'quit':
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break
    # bad command
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
```

The win condition here is `current_room['name'] == 'the Cellar'`

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! I've been pouring over this for hours. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the line of code:

```
rooms[3]
```

computers start counting at 0 so you need to change it to

```
rooms[2]
```

Comment: Even with this change, the code does not work - this is just checking which room is third in the `rooms` dictionary, not which room the player is currently in